# Awk grouping by first column

Tags: awk

I have data like this

```
prdnf001:app_prd_areas_sp2_ux  
prdnf001:app_prd_cx_local_ux  
prdnf001:app_prd_cx_ux  
prdnf001:app_prd_ftt_ux  
prdnf001:app_prd_local_ux 
prdnf001:app_prd_app_ux  
devnf001:app_syt_ds_backup1  
devnf001:app_syt_ds_sybsft1  
devnf001:app_syt_ftt_ux  
devnf001:app_syt_app_ux 
devnf001:app_uat_cx_ux
```

and I would output grouped likes this:

```
prdnf001
prdnf001:app_prd_areas_sp2_ux  
prdnf001:app_prd_cx_local_ux  
prdnf001:app_prd_cx_ux  
prdnf001:app_prd_ftt_ux  
prdnf001:app_prd_local_ux 
prdnf001:app_prd_app_ux 
devnf001 
devnf001:app_syt_ds_backup1  
devnf001:app_syt_ds_sybsft1  
devnf001:app_syt_ftt_ux  
devnf001:app_syt_app_ux 
devnf001:app_uat_cx_ux
```

This is the code I am using, so far. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks

```
awk 'split($1,svm,":");{if (svm[1] == f1) { print svm[1] }else print svm[1];f1=svm[1] }'
```

Comment: Wrap your code in CODE TAGS, you will see a button while editing your code `{}` select your sample and click on it then. Also please add your efforts which you have made to solve this problem in your post too.

Comment: Please read this; https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
awk -F ':' 'saved!=$1{saved=$1; print saved} {print}' file
```

Output:

```
prdnf001
prdnf001:app_prd_areas_sp2_ux DP prdnf001-dr:app_prd_areas_sp2_ux_m Snapmirrored 
prdnf001:app_prd_cx_local_ux DP prdnf001-dr:app_prd_cx_local_ux_m Snapmirrored 
prdnf001:app_prd_cx_ux DP prdnf001-dr:app_prd_cx_ux_m Snapmirrored 
prdnf001:app_prd_ftt_ux DP prdnf001-dr:app_prd_ftt_ux_m Snapmirrored 
prdnf001:app_prd_local_ux DP prdnf001-dr:app_prd_local_ux_m Snapmirrored 
prdnf001:app_prd_app_ux DP prdnf001-dr:app_prd_app_ux_m Snapmirrored 
devnf001
devnf001:app_syt_ds_backup1 DP tstnf001:app_syt_ds_backup1_m Snapmirrored 
devnf001:app_syt_ds_sybsft1 DP tstnf001:app_syt_ds_sybsft1_m Snapmirrored 
devnf001:app_syt_ftt_ux DP tstnf001:app_syt_ftt_ux_m Snapmirrored 
devnf001:app_syt_app_ux DP tstnf001:app_syt_app_ux_m Snapmirrored 
devnf001:app_uat_cx_ux DP tstnf001:app_uat_cx_ux_m Snapmirrored
```